# How to add a "TOTAL" level in a factor so it can be shown in a barplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this graph where I show the frequency of appearence of a pathogen in two types of samples (case or control) by type of the pathogen (it can be 40, 41 or NT). What I need is to add a bar where all types are shown as one ("TOTAL" that includes types 40, 41 and NT)
[image: Graph of frequency of the pathogen]

So I need a bar that sums all the values in controls and cases.

My data base has the following structure, where the type of pathogen will only be available (not NA) if the pathogen is present in the sample ($Pathogen==2), that is why my graph only contains "positive" results for the pathogen. (NA excluded)

```
> str(mcdf)
'data.frame':   328 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ cod_per    : chr  "NNV0026" "NNV0030" "NNV1027" "NNV1049" ...
 $ Pathogen: Factor w/ 2 levels "Ausencia","Presencia": 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 ...
 $ casecontrol: Factor w/ 2 levels "Control","Caso": 2 1 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 ...
 $ match      : int  1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 ...
 $ tipo_pathogen  : Factor w/ 3 levels "40","41","NT": NA NA NA NA NA 2 NA NA NA 3 ...
```

The code for the graph I used is the next one:

```
ggplot(na.omit(mcdf), aes(tipo_pathogen,fill=casecontrol))+
  geom_bar(position="dodge",stat="count")+
  scale_fill_discrete(name="Condición")
```

Please, I need help, because I have no idea ir ggplot has a function to add a total variable or if I can add the total level to the faactor "type_pathogen" . Should I do something to my original database? Because I have negative results that should not be considered in the "total" level.

Comment: As you suspect, you should create a new variable with this information before using ggplot.

Comment: I have created a new data frame  and also used addmargins like the answer given below. However, I am loosing information by doing these. But at least I have the graphic, thaaanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is easily done in base. I don't know an easy way to do it in ggplot2

```
data1 <- na.omit(mcdf)

counts <- addmargins(table(data1$type_pathogen , data1$casecontrol ), 1)
barplot(counts beside = TRUE, col = c(4 ,3) , legend = data1$casecontrol)
```

Comment: The problem is that I need those bars in the same graph that I originally posted. That's why I don't know how to do it

Comment: As if the sum was a new factor in the x-axis